# jQuery cloned html element mouse events in new object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, mouseover

---

**Ok so here is the situation:**

I have created an object which contains a method to (jQuery) clone and append a html element and store a reference to that new html element in the object.

I then have a loop in the main area of my code to generate a bunch of new instances of the object, for each of those new instances I run the method to create a new html element.

now thats the contexts... what im wondering is... can i put a method in the object to handle a mouseover event on the html element that is created for each instance of the object and is therefore specific for that new instance of the object... my reason being is purely neat code. I can do it out of the object easy enough by looping through the instances of the object i have made and attaching mouse events to each.

but yeah inside the method would be nice..

**this is what I have tried:**

**NOTE** in the code bellow "this.html_element" is the reference to the cloned html element thats stored in the instance of the object and "this.element_id" is a property of the instance of the object that stores a unique id.

```
this.html_element.mouseover((function(id){
    console.log(id);
})(this.element_id));
```

That to my mind should work.. and it does.. but not the way i want it to... i runs straight away without waiting for a mouseover event on the html_element... and when you do mouse over that doesn't work at all.

console log shows:

```
1
2
3
4
```

etc... which just corresponds to the number of instances of the object i have made it make.

**I have also tried:**

```
this.html_element.mouseover(function(){
    console.log(this.element_id);
});
```

which does trigger when a mouseover event happens but of course nothing is that easy and the console log spits out:

```
undefined
```

so i guess i need something in between but i cant think of what that might be... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a closure variable:

```
var self = this;
this.html_element.mouseover(function() {
    console.log(self.element_id);
});
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for that... seems i don't understand closure as well as i thought i did... time for some reading.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, what you want to achieve is adding event handlers on-the-go that depends on element's property (**id**).

If so, you should try to read jQuery's [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/). With it, you can bind event handlers to DOM elements even when it doesn't exist yet. And for the parameter, you could try grabbing from the HTML element itself by using custom attribute (only if desirable, of course).

For example, if one object is represented by one `.item` element (which will be put inside `.container`), you could add attribute `data-id` on the element:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" data-id="1">...</div>
    <div class="item" data-id="2">...</div>
    <div class="item" data-id="3">...</div>
</div>
```

And then, on the script side:

```
$('.container').on('mouseover', '.item', function () {
    var elementId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log(elementId);
});
```

Check it out on [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wkrh1jde/).

But again, it all depends on your circumstances; just suggesting an alternative.

Comment: Na sorry not quite what im after sorry... i can do all that just fine... anyway @Barmar got the right answer for me.